# Node js sequlize insert data with associations

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I have created two models with associations. The models are
merchant and store.

Merchant will have multiple stores. So that I have created hasMany relationship.

Then, I am trying to insert data like below.

```
var store = {
    name: "test - 1",
    email: "test@gmail.com",
    phone: "12312312312",
  }

  var data = {
    name: "Store",
    email: "Store@gmail.com",
    phone: "12312312312",
    store: store
  }

  models.merchant.create(data, {include : store})
```

This code is only insert merchant data only, Store data is not installed.

I don't how install merchant and store data in same query.

Please help anyone to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189253/discussion-on-question-by-az-rnd-node-js-sequlize-insert-data-with-associations).

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are wrong between store **model** and store **variable**

```
var data = {
    name: "Store",
    email: "Store@gmail.com",
    phone: "12312312312",
    store: {
        name: "test - 1",
        email: "test@gmail.com",
        phone: "12312312312",
      }
}

models.merchant.create(data, {include : models.store})
```

PS: store in include is a model when you define from sequelize. Also, you can check document to more clear about [creating with associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#creating-with-associations)

Comment: Shouldn't it be {include: data.store} ?

Comment: No, store is model when you define from sequelize

Comment: @azrnd Can you accept my answer and upvote? Thanks you

Comment: In this section models.merchant.create(data, {include : models.store}), Can we add store model relationships in include section?

Comment: Bro, This is working in inserting the data, But how to do with updating the data?